# How is routing done in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

In MvcApplication class, we call the RegisterRoutes method inside Application_Start method.Where do we create the object of RouteConfig class in the MvcApplication class so that RegisterRoutes is called?

Comment: Your _App_Start_ folder contains a *RouteConfig.cs* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. `RouteConfig` is a static class reference (`RegisterRoutes` is a static method), not an instance method, so you don't create anything.